# parameterized with session and query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, query-string

I am facing an error message and i didnt know the reason with me sql statement as at line:

```
DACatPgeVIPLIST.Fill(dsCatPgeVIPLIST);
```

It's showing this message can you help me with it:

> The parameterized query `(@Country nvarchar(7),@Category nvarchar(4000))SELECT a.[AdsID],` expects the parameter `@Category`, which was not supplied.

Code:

```
if (Session["location"] != null)
{
    using (SqlConnection CatPgeVIPLISTsqlCON = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        CatPgeVIPLISTsqlCON.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter DACatPgeVIPLIST = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT a.[AdsID], a.[Country], a.[State], a.[City], a.[AdsTit], SUBSTRING(a.[AdsDesc], 1, 70) as AdsDesc, a.[AdsPrice], a.[Img1] FROM [ads] as a INNER JOIN [UserInfo] as u on u.UID = a.UID WHERE a.[Country] = @Country and a.[Category] = @Category and u.VIP = 'Yes'", cs);

        string location = Convert.ToString(Session["location"]);
        string category = Request.QueryString["category"];

        DACatPgeVIPLIST.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", location);
        DACatPgeVIPLIST.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", category);

        DataSet dsCatPgeVIPLIST = new DataSet();

        DACatPgeVIPLIST.Fill(dsCatPgeVIPLIST);

        CatPgeVIPLIST.DataSource = dsCatPgeVIPLIST.Tables[0];
        CatPgeVIPLIST.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Grant Winney its to with value as there is another listview in same page it shown the items and it using the same session location

Comment: Have you checked that `category` has a value?

Comment: Most probably your `@Category` parameter is empty. what's the value of `Request.QueryString["category"]`?

Comment: thanks for all of you guys, after many tries i just work now its already fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for the following line of code to assign `null` to category:

```
string category = Request.QueryString["category"];
```

You could possibly get around it like this, which converts `null` to an empty string:

```
string category = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["category"]);
```

Or you could try passing `DBNull.Value` instead of `null` (untested):

```
DACatPgeVIPLIST.SelectCommand.Parameters
               .AddWithValue("@Category", (object)category ?? DBNull.Value);
```